# Google Colabrotary expected an indented block

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Google Colabrotary is failing with *IndentationError: expected an indented block*.

#### Code

```
def zero_pad(X, pad):
    X_pad = np.pad( X, ((0,0), (pad,pad), (pad,pad), (0,0)), 'constant', 
    constant_values)
    return X_pad`
```

#### Error

```
File "<ipython-input-4-a7791c18ae10>", line 2
    X_pad = np.pad( X, ((0,0), (pad,pad), (pad,pad), (0,0)), 'constant', constant_values)
        ^
***IndentationError: expected an indented block***
```

Comment: This isn't reproducible as written, and I have no idea what "space" is referred to in the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just remove the space before the def block and code like this:

```
import numpy as np
def zero_pad(X, pad):
  X_pad = np.pad(X, ((0,0), (pad,pad), (pad,pad), (0,0)), 'constant', constant_values) 
  return X_pad
```